# Need to add a date reference (MAX(DATE)) that returns a quantity that occurred on that day. I can't add the actual date

Tags: mysql, date, subquery, filtering, case-statement

I need to return a quantity level that happened on a certain day, but I can't add the actual day, because we're talking about hundreds of thousands of records. I need to be able to say something like:

```
Case When max(date) then count(quantity) end as 'Count'
```

I can't do this due to the aggregate not being an actual argument. Nor can I put this in my where clause, for the same reason. I have tried to write it as:

```
Case When max(date)=max(date) then count(quantity) end
```

but it doesn't work either. When I put this in my where clause, it works, but returns an incorrect count. Surely there is some way to pull data for dates. I have been searching for this for a couple of days, and the best I could find was how to write the statement to pull dates, but not to combine them with something that pulls another output.

Additionally, I need to add this to a larger query (subquery), but I don't want the larger query to filter based on this date. I do want to join it to my larger query though so it will return the quantity found for each item_number. Thanks in advance for any assistance.

This is the code that works to find the correct date and the subsequent count of pallets. But it provides different results when joined to the parent query.

```
(SELECT
b.item_no as 'Item No',
max(x.Date),
count(b.PKG_ID)

From
wsPKGaud a 
join wspkglin b 
on a.PKG_ID = b.PKG_ID
right outer Join    (select 
            b.item_no as 'Item No',
            cast(max(a.aud_dt) as date) as [Date]
            from 
            wsPKGaud a 
            join wspkglin b 
            on a.PKG_ID = b.PKG_ID
            where           
            a.aud_action = 'A'
            group by 
            b.Item_no
            ) x
            on a.aud_dt=x.Date and b.Item_no=x.[Item No]
where           
a.aud_action = 'A'
and a.aud_dt=x.Date
and b.Item_no=x.[Item No]

group by 
b.Item_no)
```

Comment: What database system are you using (e.g. [tag:mysql], [tag:sql-server], [tag:oracle]). They all talk "SQL" but have various specific features that may help here. Also, what *version* of the product?

Comment: MS SQL server accessed through SSMS

Comment: can't really do it in a single query, since the max() result wouldn't be available (yet) at the time the per-row `where` filtering is occuring. you'd need a second query (even if it's a subquery of some sort) to fetch the max data, which can then be used in the parent query.

Comment: That's an interesting thought. I'm going to try it now. Thank you.

Comment: Ok, adding the date as a subquery DID WORK! Thank you. Now do you have any suggestions for adding this to a parent query without filtering the results on the rest of the query to be that date?

Comment: So I have the issue now where I add it to the parent query that it is being built for and when connected, it no longer provides the correct output. On it's own, the query is working correctly.

Comment: I am adding it in my join, and referencing the two fields that I need, date and count in my select statement.

Comment: Got it!!! It needed to be added in the join, but then, since I needed the most recent transaction quantity, I had to request max from my subquery. I was originally counting the subquery in the parent query, so I was getting too much as a result. Thanks for all the help!!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When adding to the parent query, I joined the subquery and requested max(date) and max(count) instead of continuing to ask for count(PKG_ID). The subquery already counted the PKG_ID, and when I was requesting a second count, I got a much larger output. Thanks guys!